# Need to convert <Pipe+NewLine+Pipe> into <Pipe>, failing at it

Tags: excel, vba

I'm parsing somewhat garbage data. Sometimes the users delimit with a pipe character. Other times they delimit with a pipe, a carriage return+line feed and another pipe.

I don't want to just clean out all of the new lines without first identifying where they are. in order to harmonize the data I need to convert pipe-crlf-pipe into a single pipe. Just yanking them out would then create "||". That's an issue because pipe-pipe, when the single pipe delimiter is used indicates a blank field, which we need to preserve.

Example:

```
|FieldA|FieldB|FieldC|

or

|FieldA|
|FieldB|
|FieldC|
```

are how the data is formatted.

There's nothing I can do about the inconsistency other than work with it.

Despite this block of code I'm running the text string through...

```
myData = Replace(myData, "|"+vbCrLf+"|", "|")
myData = Replace(myData, Chr(124)+vbCrLf+Chr(124), Chr(124))
myData = Replace(myData, Chr(124)+Chr(13)+Chr(10)+Chr(124), Chr(124))
myData = Replace(myData, Chr(124)+Chr(10)+Chr(13)+Chr(124), Chr(124))
myData = Replace(myData, "|"+Chr(13)+Chr(10)+"|", "|")
myData = Replace(myData, "|"+Chr(10)+Chr(13)+"|", "|")
```

They still come through. I tried regular expressions but it didn't seem to work either.

I just can't get the code to convert any instances of Pipe+NewLine+Pipe into Pipe.

I pulled the data into a hex editor to make sure it's not some other character sometimes it is just 0A linefeed, but mostly... it's 7C0D0A7C

Comment: Is the data in a text file or ?  Can you share a little more code to put this in context?

Comment: Maybe first normalize all vbCrLf to vbLf, and the perform the replace on `"|" & vbLf & "|"`

Comment: a) VbCrLf => VbLf
........b) VbCr = > VbLf
.......c) " " => ""
.......d) Chr(160) => ""
.......e) "|" & VbLf & "|"  => "|" ........ if it doesn't work it's better to analyze some lines of your data to see the character codes and act accordingly.